Как скрыть токен тг-бота на гитхабе?
Хочу выложить бота на гитхаб, но нужно скрыть токен, помогите пожалуйста!!!

Удалите токен, закоммитьте и залейте. В чем проблема?

Вам надо поместить назвайла файла с токеном в файл .gitignore. Подробнее тут

связанный вопрос

Сначала скачиваешь python-dotenv, командой
pip install python-dotenv

Далее необходимо создать файл с переменными окружения, он должен называться .env, в нем создать создать переменную
BOT_TOKEN=и тут твой токен

Далее импортируешь эти переменные в свой main файл следующим образом
from dotenv import load_dotenv 

load_dotenv()
# Получаем переменные окружения
BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")

Теперь можешь обращаться к BOT_TOKEN, там содержится твой токен.
